# Unsure about what the 'control may reach end of non-void function' error message means

Tags: c

Trying to execute a search using a pseudo random generator to find whether value is in array.  Every time I execute I get the following message:

```
helpers.c:46:1: error: control may reach end of non-void function [-Werror,-Wreturn-type]
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
bool search (int value, int values[], int n)
{             
if (n > 0)
{     
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (value == values[i])
            return true;
        else
            return false;                        
    }    

}
else
    return false;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic appears to be wrong .Change

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
 {
     if (value == values[i])
         return true;
     else
         return false;
 }
```

To

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
 {
     if (value == values[i])
         return true;
 }
 return false;
```

Otherwise, the loop will not execute more than one time.

The error message tells you that if `if (n > 0)` is true and the condition in `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)` is false, then you don't return a `bool` (The compiler isn't intelligent enough to know that this won't happen)

Comment: The change you suggested should fix the problem.  I believe that the JDK would not complain about this problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a scenario where you doesn't enter into the for loop.. Then no value will be returned. You should return something after the for loop or at the end of the function